# Postman TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: postman

I'm running tests in Postman. In the following request body, I need to check if the `items` list is empty:

```
{
    "name": "k",
    "items": []
}
```

The code snippet below works:

```
var responseJson = pm.response.json(); 
pm.test("Items should be initially empty", function () {
    pm.expect(responseJson.items).to.be.an('array').that.is.empty;`
 });
```

I've tried modifying my code as shown below. But I need to know where I have made a mistake.

```
var responseJson = pm.response.json(); 
tests["Items should be initially empty"] = responseJson.items.length === 0;
```

Comment: Why are you mixing the old and new syntax, in the first test. I wouldn't even recommend using the old tests object. That was used over 5 major versions ago and was succeeded by `pm.test()`.